# 90s kid Blockbuster rental, sci-fi animated film

Tags: story-identification, movie

I really don’t remember much I was quite little (7-8) when I watched this film. I remember it giving me *Star Wars* vibes.

The main male character (teen) has like a mentor or something, and after a fight the kid is left blind and has to carry on his mission or something… he had a bandana on his eyes and it was a cliffhanger ending. (How will the Main character fulfill his mission? What about his mentor?)

The animation style could not have been 60s and if anything it fit the style of late 70s. Any suggestions would be great. I’ve spent hours upon hours trying to find this film but maybe it was just a niche find at a blockbuster. :(

Sorry for the constant edits but it felt like some sorta future dystopian gunslinger post apocalyptic setting  I just remember the teen boy gets blinded and it’s a cliffhanger ending and it drove me nuts as a kid but I forgot about it until my adult years. I need closure damnit!

Maybe there was no mentor but it definitely was in a dystopian future (not *Stargazers*).

Gosh I wish I knew what this was I have dreams about it every few years but I don’t remember much.

Comment: I looked for an animated film called _Stargazers_ (to see what the animation style looked like), but couldn't find any information on such a film, if one with that title exists. Did you mean to type _[Star Blazers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Blazers)_? If so, that's a TV series, not a film, so do you believe you might be looking for an episode of a series rather than a film? Also, was the animation style of the film (or episode) you're looking for similar to _Star Blazers_? If not, then what else was it most similar to, visually?

Comment: Starchasers is a very star wars like cartoon but doesn't really match blinded part.  Quest for Camelot has a blinded character but obviously isn't a future dystopia.

Comment: Sorry starchaser legend of Orin was the movie I was referring it… which it is not haha

Comment: Honestly it could have been a series with episodes… I really remember so little. The animation style was not Japanese it was definitely American. It was at blockbuster so it’s totally possible that they just packaged together 3-4 episodes on a vhs.

Comment: Bravestarr was a 1980s space western "gunslinger" series.  https://youtu.be/I_E3gfQc6AQ